# mongoose (mongodb) weird behaviour when querying with no params

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Postman to post to my backend to get a user based on his username and password.

Whenever the username doesn't exist as a field in the form, a user is still returned (I only have one user at the moment and he is returned);

But, if I add the username field, it returns null unless it is the correct username, even if its empty.

this is the code:

```
 User.findOne({
    username: req.body.username
  }, function(err, user) {
    if(err) throw err;

    // prints null if username field is present and incorrect even if its empty
    // prints a user as json if the username field is not present
    console.log(user); 
    if(!user) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
    }
```

I am still checking for a password so it won't work for someone to post without a username field but it is very odd and prevents the right error message to display. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check first if the parameter exists, or `req.body.username` will equal `undefined` which will result in an empty query.

`findOne` with an empty query will fetch the first document found, as you can get all the documents with `find` with an empty query.

An empty string won't result as an empty query which is why you get `null` (you don't have any user with `''` as username).

TLDR: Check the presence of every parameter before building the query and return some `409 MissingParameterError` if you are building a REST api.